# RSS Viewer Web Part Loading Error

Tags: 2013, web-part, content-query-web-part, rss

Working in SP13 and the RSS Viewer Web Part is available.  The web part came over from a site original created in SP10. It worked when it entered into SP13 however it's not working now.  Things I have done to correct the problem was to delete the web part and put another on the site.  However, the URL does not work.  This error appears when applying the URL "An unexpected error occurred when processing your request. See logs for further information and correct the error."  I checked the URL in the browser and it worked fine.

What I want to be able to do is to show each RSS Feed (total of 4 on a page) as individual feeds on a page.

To resolve the issue I tried many things.

1. I have searched and found many questions about the same problem.  Many had no answers.
2. I found another solution to create a content query web part.  But found no clear steps on how to do so.
3. Tried to show the RSS Feed page by using the Page Viewer web part, but the URL will not show.  Is this because it's an RSS Feed?
4. I haven't checked the Kerberos authentication , but if worked a week ago wouldn't mean the Kerberos is on?

Has anyone ran across this issue in SP13?

Note: To get to the RSS Feed an username/password is to be entered if you just use the company URL.  The RSS Feed URL (short cut URL) does not work in the RSS Viewer web part.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I recently had a similar problem and found that it was related to the gZip compression on the server delivering the RSS content to Share Point.

The RSS validated to the W3C RSS Validator and worked in any browser but not as a SharePoint source.

In my case I disabled gZip compression on the application server (Lucee, Java) but kept compression on IIS